# comparing two arraylist with condition in Java

Tags: java, string, if-statement, arraylist

I have printed two array lists from two CSV files

CSV 1 to arraylist

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(stream));
String text = br.readLine();
String[] b = text.split(String.valueOf(str));
csv1.add(b[0]);
```

CSV 2 to arraylist

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(stream));
String text = br.readLine();
String[] b = text.split(String.valueOf(str));
csv2.add(b[0]);
```

I need to compare column names but they are labelled differently in each file. column John in list 1 is equal to col smith in list 2

```
ArrayList1 = ["John","Jane","Vehicle","Snack","Ring"]
ArrayList2 = ["Car","Bar","Smith","Doe","Ring"]
```

For example; John in list1 has all the same data as smith in list2. I need to check if John is present in list one, then smith SHOULD be present in list 2 and check for that column name.

Comment: Can you share the code you've written so far in attempt to solve this problem?

Comment: Are the values in each list position dependent?  And this has all indications that a class might serve  you better.

Comment: @WJS No they are not position dependent

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy Added code for ref

Comment: *No they are not position dependent*.  So `john` could be a the front of `list1` and `Smith` could be at the end of `list2`?

Comment: @WJS Yes but some columns might be named the same for example Ring in both columns have the same name and so that would print true

Comment: @Darkman John in list1 has all the same data as smith in list2. I need to check, if column John is present in list one, then smith SHOULD be present in list 2 and check for that column name.

Answer (score 0):

The method takes two lists and two supplied strings and checks to see if both strings appear in opposing lists.

```
public boolean checkName(List<String> list1, List<String> 
    list2, String one, String two) {
     return list1.contains(one) && list2.contains(two) ||
            list1.contains(two) && list2.contains(one);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a map if you know which column names are linked to each other.

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("John", "Smith");
map.put("Jane", "Doe");
map.put("Vehicle", "Car");
map.put("Snack", "Bar");
map.put("Ring", "Ring");
```

**EDIT**

Assuming you have read the content of the files into lists as given in your example and your list contain:

```
//code to read file content into lists
//....

ArrayList1 = ["John","Jane","Vehicle","Snack","Ring"]
ArrayList2 = ["Car","Bar","Smith","Doe","Ring"]
```

you can iterate over the first list and check against second list:

```
for (String column : ArrayList1) {
    boolean found = ArrayList2.stream().anyMatch(map.get(column)::equals);
    if (found){
        System.out.println(String.format("Found matching columns: %s -> %s.", column, map.get(column)));
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(String.format("No matching column found for: %s.", column));
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of `String lineFromFirstCsv  = "John,Jane,Vehicle,Snack,Ring"; String lineFromSecondCsv = "Car,Bar,Smith,Doe,Ring";` how can I use the arraylist output from my bufferreader? thanks in advance

Comment: @JoeyOC please see my edit on how to use the lists instead